# Nginx SSL_Shutdown() failed

Tags: nginx, ssl

We use Nginx for mTLS authentication for our server. And we keep getting this error randomly

```
28#28: *2271614 SSL_shutdown() failed (SSL: error:14094123:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:application data after close notify) while SSL handshaking, client: XX.XX.XX.XX server: XX.XX.XX.XX
8#28: *2271614 X509_verify_cert() failed while SSL handshaking, client: XX.XX.XX.XX server: XX.XX.XX.XX
```

The error happens more frequent on some specific SSL client certificate. We have tried to enable logging and debug but no luck. There are success requests from the same client using the same certificates.

Here is our nginx config:

```
server {
    listen ${SSL_LISTEN_PORT} ssl;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" always;

    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/server_cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/server_key.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/pki/trusted_ca_cert.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 3;

    ssl_stapling ${SERVER_OCSP_STAPLING};
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/pki/trusted_ca_cert.pem;

    ssl_ocsp ${CLIENT_OCSP};
    ssl_ocsp_cache shared:clientOCSPCache:20m;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    proxy_read_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    resolver local=on ipv6=off; # openresty: local=on makes nginx use /etc/resolv.conf
    set $upstream ${TARGET_PROTOCOL}://${TARGET_HOSTNAME}:${TARGET_PORT};
    set $client_domain_name '';
    set $service_env ${SERVICE_ENV};

    # hide server version
    server_tokens off;
```

Comment: These are very likely unrelated errors and they have nothing to do with your config. One is about the client sending data after SSL shutdown - check the client. One is about a client certificate which cannot be validated - check what certificate the client used.